# CURL returns the page with errors (JS, CSS, etc errors)

Tags: php, curl, iframe, pentaho

Actually I saw some similar cases in Stack Overflow but seems I have errors in my PHP code and can not show the page correctly. The Page I am trying to get is a resource from Pentaho BI. (Version 7.1.0.0.12). I tried many, many things, but nothing works.

- Firstly I perform the authentication by 'Cookie-Based Authentication' (the method provided by Pentaho) -> Information: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0R0/070/010/00A

In order to get the Cookie, I perform an HTTP POST by CURL PHP. That works well, I am able to get the Cookie from Pentaho.
Please check the code below;

```
    $post_data['username'] = "suzy";
    $post_data['password'] = "password";
    foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
      $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    $post_string = implode('&', $post_items);
    $curl_connection = curl_init('http://10.10.10.215:8080/pentaho/j_spring_security_check');
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3000 * 10);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username=suzy&j_password=password');
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
    $sessionID = explode("=", $url);
    $cookie = $sessionID[1];
```

So, the variable $cookie contains the SESSIONID that I should use to access to the resource from Pentaho.

And then I perform an HTTP GET by CURL PHP in order to get the page (resource) from Pentaho.
This is the part that doesn't work. Actually what can I see is that PHP is "connected" to Pentaho by the URL and the Cookie I previously requested, and also the call returns the whole page, but when I displays the page in the browser it throws a lot of errors as I said before (JS, CSS errors and more).
Please check the code bellow;

```
    $url = "http://10.10.10.215:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Apublic%3ASteel%20Wheels%3ADashboards%3ACTools_dashboard.wcdf/generatedContent";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en_US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/plain,* /*;q=0.01';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
    $headers[] = 'Cookie: JSESSIONID='.$sessionID[1];
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    echo $response;die();
```

I'd like to clarify, I am able to get the page but with all of those erros I mentioned.
I have also tried to get this content into an IFRAME but couldn't do it. Is there any way to do it?
All information you can add is welcome! If you have some code that I can check, and more, as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually? I don't see how it is PHP related.

Comment: If the page contains any relative URLs, the browser will interpret them relative to the location of the PHP script. It doesn't know that the script fetches the page from a different location.

Comment: There's not really any practical way to make this work.